# Code in constructor before this or super in generated class file while using code coverage tool

Tags: java, code-coverage

I am using google code pro Analatics to measure code coverage.

Source code

```
public class StackArray<T> implements Stack<T> {
    private int top;
    private T[] elements;

    public StackArray(Class<T> type, int size) {
        top = -1;
        elements = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, size);
    }

    //Other stack related methods
}
```

Generated class file

```
import com.vladium.emma.rt.RT;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

// Referenced classes of package ds.stack:
//            Stack

public class StackArray implements Stack {

    private int top;
    private Object elements[];
    private static final int $VRc[][]; /* synthetic field */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x927be770ed420794L; /* synthetic field */

    public StackArray(Class type, int size)
    {
        int ai[] = ($VRc != null ? $VRc : $VRi())[0];
        super();
        top = -1;
        elements = (Object[])Array.newInstance(type, size);
        ai[0] = ai[0] + 1;
    }
}
```

My question is how is this line permissible in constructor before this or super

```
int ai[] = ($VRc != null ? $VRc : $VRi())[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

The restriction on `super()` or `this()` being allowed only as the first instruction in a constructor is a limitation imposed by Java compilers, not byte-code/object classes.

The "generated class file" is either a de-compilation of an object class that will not compile under a regular Java compiler, or is compatible with an altered Java allowing such constructs.  In both cases the code looks 99% a Java source file, but it is not.

Comment: +1 While you cannot put lines of code before this and super, you can put expressions as arguments to those methods which can evaluate things.